# How to initialize a int const * const in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

exp. I have a

```
class foo{
    public:
      int const * const array;
      size_t const length;
}
```

There should be no changes on these variables after construction, including by any member methods, but the values should be accessible by everyone, so they should be constant.

But in the constructor, I need to decide the length first before I can initialize the array,

Besides, I need to call a function to allocate the memory location, instead of just a `new`, because this class is a bridge to a huge opaque data structure, and the memory is managed by that guy.(consider sth. like v8).

How can I initialize in this?

p.s. lets just call the allocator `void * bar(size_t)`, and the constructor (maybe) looks like:

```
foo(size_t const len, int const *arr) {
    this->array = reinterpret_cast<int *> (bar(len));
    this->length = len;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) array[i] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: I assume your constructor takes a `const int*` parameter and a `length` or something similar? If so, this is trivial. If not, this is unsolvable, because we only know what outputs you want, without any inputs.

Comment: "in the constructor, I need to decide the length first before I can initialize the array," Correct. So do that. What is the problem?

Comment: Don't see a constructor in your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I considered this way, I need to mark every member methods 'const' in that case, and I also need to write getters for these values and mark them private.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Absolute nonsense. Dynamically initialized values can totally be and absolutely should be const.

Comment: @YongjianWang the loop you show will not work since `array` is pointing at `const` values that can't be assigned to

Comment: More specifically, `int const *arr` points to `const` data, and that `reinterpret_cast` is _extremely_ dangerous and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the constructor's *member initializer list* like this:

```
class Test {

    public:
    Test(size_t length): length(length), array(func_to_allocate(length)) {}

    size_t const length;
    int const * const array;
};
```

Note: There is nothing in the body of the constructor `{}` all the initialization happens *before* it is run.

Comment: but I can not use 'new', I know I can do it this way, but I just can not use new

Comment: @YongjianWang: Then don't. Simply call `bar()` instead: `array(static_cast<int const *>(bar(length)))`

Comment: You don't need to re-order the members (although that does appear clearer), as long as you know you're using the `length` parameter (and not the `length` member) in the constructor.  OTOH, re-ordering may be useful if `length` is somehow computed (expensively) rather than being provided as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you can't rearrange the members (or it's not helpful to do so), then this is the answer. If you can rearrange members and it's helpful to do so, then [Galik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620372/845092)  is superior.

It's hard to tell from your question, but I'm going to make a series of wild speculations, and then show the resulting code:

```
class bridge {
public:
  int const * const array;
  size_t const length;

  bridge(const sourceType& source);

private:
    static int const* init_array(const sourceType& source);
};

int const* bridge::init_array(const sourceType& source) {
    int len = source.getLength();
    int* arr = static_cast<int*>(bar(len));
    fill(arr, len);
    return arr;
}

bridge::bridge(const sourceType& source) :
    array(init_array(source)),
    length(source.getLength())
{}
```

That look viable?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize members in the initializer list:

```
foo(size_t const len, int const *arr)
  : array(reinterpret_cast<int*>(bar(len))),
    length(len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) array[i] = arr[i];
}
```

You can help yourself get this right, using **`g++ -Weffc++`**, or your compiler's equivalent.